# Issue with a "dirty" system SSD and chkdsk on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

Since yesterday my desktop computer has been booting with a "To skip disk checking, press any key within X second(s.)" message on the regular Windows startup screen. I didn't press any keys to skip and it looked like it was running disk checking with another message along the lines of "Scanning and repairing" but that screen cuts to black after about 3 seconds. I get my log on screen as usual, which is unfamiliar with my usual experience with Chkdsk. And now every time I boot up my computer I get the same disk checking screen. I have found no issues or corrupt files with my system but keep in mind I've used it for only a day since this whole thing started.

Querying the disk using `fsutil` in Command Prompt confirmed that the C: drive was dirty even after multiple boots. The properties tab of my C: drive in Explorer also says that there are problems with my disk. Looking at Event Viewer I found one occurrence of an error with the Event ID of 55 from yesterday and multiple occurrences of an error with the Event ID of 98 for every time I started the computer.
(I can show the details tab of the Event Properties window if it's needed.)

So, either my disk is corrupt or at least the system thinks it is and chkdsk is not working to fix it or clearing the dirty tag on my disk. I've already ran SFC and DISM but they haven't found anything.

My history with this SSD is that it's 2 years old and is a clone of an older SSD with Windows installed. I haven't had any integrity or corruption issues with it apart from one irate Windows update that caused the computer to blue screen on every boot but that was fixed by just booting into safe mode and running SFC.

I've been scouring the internet for the entire day now looking for a fix but I've not been able to find a case that's close to mine. The obvious solution that seemed to me was running `chkdsk C: /f /r` in Command Prompt but I shied away from doing it because the few occurrences I read of people running it was that again, chkdsk did nothing and they got the usual log on screen or worse, their system got completely stuck at the boot screen. One solution I kept seeing in Microsoft Forums by one specific moderator was running `chkdsk C: /f /r` in the Windows Recovery Environment but turns out I have my Windows RE image on the wrong disk and thus can't run it... oops.

This is why I decided to bring up my issue here since the only option I think I have is mounting a Windows installation media and copying its recovery image files to my system and trying the Microsoft Forums solution I gave above but I have doubts if that's going to work as well since it's more than likely that the respective Windows builds will be different. So, I'm looking for a second opinion on how to resolve this before trying that out later. Any help and ideas are very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Added screenshots of running chkdsk without any parameters and of CrystalDiskInfo

[image: Results of chkdsk from command prompt]

[image: Screenshot of CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: Run `chkdsk C:` without the other parameters just to check for errors and let us know the results. Add also to your post a screenshot of the SMART attributes of the disk (if you don't have a product for this you may use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the response. I've ran ```chkdsk C:``` as you've suggested and have attached a screenshot of the results. I've had CrystalDiskInfo installed already so I also added a screenshot from it, hope that helps.

Comment: The disk is in good shape. Try to test Windows integrity by running `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and then `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: Just ran them and Dism completed successfully and sfc didn't find any integrity violations.

Comment: How are you shutting down the computer ?

Comment: Only from the start menu.

Comment: My guess is that the disk is indeed "dirty" since the shutdown doesn't correctly dismount the disk. Does this problem happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I'm sorry but which problem are you referring to? Is it the disk checking prompt only appearing for a few seconds?

Comment: Is the disk still "dirty" when booting in Safe mode and shutting down from this mode?

Comment: Yes, it is but chkdsk is actually running this time. Currently waiting for it to finish. I think I'll check with ```fsutil``` when it's done.

Comment: Would be funny if booting in Safe mode has fixed something. Let me know.

Comment: Umm, chkdsk ran and restarted but the computer didn't boot into safe mode. fsutil says it is NOT dirty. Wow.

Comment: I added an answer. If you think it's correct, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like booting into Safe mode has cleared up the problem
and allowed chkdsk to truly terminate and clear up the condition.

I can only assume that some installed non-Microsoft product was
not allowing the shutdown to terminate correctly, so on the next
boot the disk was "dirty" again.

Comment: Would've taken me ages to try this, thank you very much for the responsiveness and the time save. Best wishes.